# Execute external php script as cron in laravel 5 job scheduler

Tags: laravel-5, cron, scheduler

I am trying to execute an external php script using laravel job scheduler. The script works fine when executed using cron tab, However, when  I try to run this via scheduler using the command below

```
 $schedule->exec("/home/script.php")->cron('* * * * * *');
```

It does not perform any operation. Is there anything which I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the following Cron entry to your server

```
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```